# Declare a new file extension as text so it is viewable in XCode and Finder

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I am trying to get a text file with a 3rd party extension of .mkb so that it will be viewable within XCode. Currently, if I right click and "Open As", it will only let me open it as a Hex file. I believe the solution might involve editing the plist file of the owning application, but none of my changes to the plist this have been successful in changing XCode or Finders behavior.

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation have you read that made you think of the Info.plist without actually explaining what you have to do?

Comment: In particular, have you read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html and defined a new UTI that conforms to plain text and has extension mkb?